# Hibernate Session in Thread with UserThread and Serialization

Tags: java, hibernate, concurrency

I have the following case:
I have a thread which uses the session to save or update

```
public void run()
{
    Session session = DAO.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
        try
    {

        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
             }catch.....
     }
```

But in the meantime during the serialization with session.saveorUpdate i change the entity object...
So the User-thread will change the data during the session serialization..

How can I overcome this problem? is there a simple way in hibernate?

EDIT:
The biggest problem lies when the UserThread changes some data in the entity object durignt the saveOrUpdate method.

Comment: So you're not saying that you want to use the same session between threads, just that you want to coordinate the threads with the transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you'd be interested in optimistic concurrency control using versioning.

### Optimistic Concurrency Control

If you haven't come across it before, it's a similar idea to compare-and-swap whereby Hibernate will manage a version along with the entity. By incrementing a version number during updates and checking it hasn't changed after, Hibernate can detect conflict and error. It optimistically assumes that *actual* contention is rare and leaves it to the developer to handle the exceptions. I've generally found this to be the case and as the Hibernate docs put it;

> The only approach that is consistent with high concurrency and high
>   scalability, is optimistic concurrency control with versioning.

You can tweak Hibernate's transaction visibility and isolation level to affect the finer details, see

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-optimistic

### Transaction Demarcation

I can't tell from the question's code snippet but it may also be worth considering the transaction boundary. Usually, I'll start a transaction (`beginTransaction`) at the start of a business operation or request and commit and completion. All updates are performed in this session (with one thread-per-session Hibernate) model. I still have each business operation or request processed on their own thread and rely on usual Hiernate issolation levels etc to manage conflicts.

I mention it because there may be a chance to step back and consider why you make updates from multiple threads. It may be that your application doesn't suit the approach I've tried to outline but it may be worth considering if it can be shifted around to avoid genuine multiple-thread updates.

Failing that it's certainly worth understanding if there is likely to be frequent conflicts in production. Testing this could help you understand if you really need to worry about it or if you can rely on the usually transaction control to detect conflicts and handle them in other ways.

Comment: Optimistic locking will only signal (usually via an Exception) that the data you're trying to update was modified in the mean time, and thus not let you update it. It doesn't solve the problem of being able to ensure that a certain update will happen and that THAT data will not be modified from the time you read it and up until you  send an update.

Comment: agreed but detecting the exception may allow you to do something about it an preserve the business flow. For example, reload and retry.  I agree it doesn't solve the problem you describe but being 'optimistic' it offers an alternative to thinking of the problem in terms of constraints. Rather than phrase the problem "I can not modify X while Y is modifying it", it's more about "what happens if X and Y clash on update?".

Comment: This is AWESOME.... but it is not a solution that I want for my exact problem.. which is now solved, but complitely from other side.. but it is an answer for this thread, so it will get the check !! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

One way is to synchronize on the entity object:

```
public void run()
{
    Session session = DAO.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
        try
    {

        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        synchronized(entity) {
            session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
        }
     }
```

Comment: well that will hurt my thread approach.. a lot.. I mean i canoot store multiple objects, because each thread will wait for some other to finish its serialization or I am wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't need to synchronize the set methods on entities but instead rely on the ACID database/hibernate mechanisms. That's what the transaction are for!

Comment: change on object durign a thread write in database.. has nothing to do to reling on ACID transcations, they are two different threads, which do two different tasks.. one is on ACID the other is userThread in code..